# Nginx rewrite for old browsers

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have the following config file that works for everything but PHP pages.

I am trying to get everything as an ancient_browser to add /IE/ in the URL.  Essentially changing the root for these clients although you cannot set this within an if.

If I add the rewrite within the PHP location it doesn't work either.  Any ideas?

```
location / {
    if ($ancient_browser) {
        rewrite  ^(.*)$ /IE/$1 break;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            if (-f $request_filename) {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting the rewrite at the beginning or the end of the PHP location block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me (nginx 1.2.3):

```
    if ($ancient_browser) {
        set $ab "/IE";
    }
    location / {
        try_files $ab$uri $ab$uri/ $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
```